TurfJs intersection issue
I am trying to implement map objects (Street Zones) which will if intersect with other street zones, bend them around. I've implemented next logic: when the drawing of zone is finished, I am trying to find all intersections of it with other zones using intersection function from turfjs, then I am uniting all of the intersection with union and using difference with original object,
Getting Union intersection fn (truncated is used to compensate distance between boundaries):
  private getUnionIntersection(feature: Feature<Polygon>, featuresToGetIntersectionsWith: Feature<Polygon>[]) {

    const format = new GeoJSON();
    const feaPoly = format.writeFeatureObject(feature) as GeoJSONPolygon;
    
    const intersections = featuresToGetIntersectionsWith
      .filter(existingFea =>
        existingFea.get('type') !== feature.get('type') ||
        existingFea.getId() !== feature.getId())
      .map((existingFea) => {
        const existingFeaturePoly = format.writeFeatureObject(existingFea) as GeoJSONPolygon;
        return intersect(feaPoly, existingFeaturePoly);
      })
      .filter(intersection => intersection);


    if (!intersections.length) { return null; }

    return intersections
      .reduce((prev, curr) => union(truncate(prev), truncate(curr)));
  } 

Bending function:
    public bendMapObj(feature: Feature<Polygon>, featuresToBend: Feature<Polygon>[], objType: string | number, ignoreMultiPolygon = false): BendingResultType {

        try {
      const format = new GeoJSON();
      const feaPoly = format.writeFeatureObject(feature) as GeoJSONPolygon;
      const unionIntersection = this.getUnionIntersection(feature, featuresToBend);
      if (!unionIntersection) { return; }
      const diff = difference(feaPoly, unionIntersection) as GeoJSONPolygon | GeoJSONMultiPolygon;

      if (!diff) { throw Error('Inner fea'); }
      if (diff.geometry.type === 'MultiPolygon' && !ignoreMultiPolygon) { throw Error('Many shapes'); }
      
      return { difference: diff, intersection: unionIntersection, bendedFeatures: featuresToBend };
        } catch (e) {
            this.handleBendError(objType, e);
            throw Error(e.message);
        }
    }

As you can see the only suitable case for difference result is polygon in my case. Everything works fine when creating first two street zones, the problems start to appear when the third is drawn.
Coords of first polygon (blue on the screenshot):
[
   [
       9227079.586445518,
       7361106.72521227
   ],
   [
       9226950.666712714,
       7358240.1570358025
   ],
   [
       9229240.8878484,
       7358528.330556187
   ],
   [
       9227079.586445518,
       7361106.72521227
   ]
]

Coords of second polygon (purple on the screenshot)
[
   [
       9227891.022410812,
       7361228.061431374
   ],
   [
       9227789.82178895,
       7360259.4269078225
   ],
   [
       9229240.8878484,
       7358528.330556187
   ],
   [
       9229230.813561888,
       7358527.062930729
   ],
   [
       9229976.488676753,
       7358452.495419242
   ],
   [
       9227891.022410812,
       7361228.061431374
   ]
]

Coords of intersection of the first(blue) and new polygon (red):
[
   [
       9227440.736314,
       7359644.350225
   ],
   [
       9228159.754835,
       7359818.103274
   ],
   [
       9227491.252183,
       7360615.615209
   ],
   [
       9227440.736314,
       7359644.350225
   ]
]

Coords of intersection of the second (purple) and new polygon (red)
[
   [
       9227789.821789,
       7360259.426908
   ],
   [
       9228159.754835,
       7359818.103274
   ],
   [
       9228476.375107,
       7359894.615543
   ],
   [
       9227821.439394,
       7360562.052554
   ],
   [
       9227789.821789,
       7360259.426908
   ]
]

The result of union of truncated intersection geometries is multipolygon with both intersections presented in it. I need to have only one united polygon. Moreover, because of the truncate difference returns polygon with points left on boundaries of intersections:

Red polygon is what i am drawing, salad part of it is what needs to stay after difference result

all coord are in web mercator projection(EPSG:3857)

Your approach seems overcomplicated.   Would it be easier to union all the existing geometries then obtain the difference between that and the new geometry as when drawing features in  https://jsfiddle.net/wfmtqbr4/

It's not quite clear what you want as end result. One union polygon without internal lines?

@Mike it seems to work pretty good until the moment i am saving my coords to db. Before saving map object i am converting all of its coordinates using 'toLonLat() function'. I found out that converting to lonLat and immediately back to espg:3857 gives some inaccuracy. I have tried to fix it by truncating EPSG:3857 coord to 7 decimal symbols, but after that i am starting to receive weird results from difference -  intersection of already existing zones is being included into difference result

@Mike my current code looks like https://qtext.io/snw0 (symbols limitation in answer)
https://imgur.com/a/YFstlqs - what i mean by "weird difference". I have circled border of already existing zones which are included in difference result

@TomazicM i want to have one union polygon representing difference with polygons which it intersects. Some context has appeared in our discussion with Mike

I admit that in sentence "one union polygon representing difference with polygons which it intersects." I don't understand what you man by "representing difference with polygons which it intersects".

@TomazicM you can see it in a screenshot attached to question. The red polygon is being drawn and some of it parts are being intersected by already existing polygons (blue one and purple). I need to substitute all of the intersections with existing polygons from drawn one. Mike gave me an example of how to do it and it works but i am having hard time with switching between projections because of inaccuracy

@TomazicM summarizing, referring to a attached screenshot,
I need only the salad part of red polygon to remain

@Mike
I have reattached my current code https://imgur.com/a/dzfi3Qb (screenshot + text version in a description)

You need all the precision JavaScript allows otherwise the calculated intersection vertices will not lie exactly on the edges of the existing polygons.
